# Is it correct to say "banks and financial institutions"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

When writing about Banking & Finance, it's so tempting to refer to business customers as "banks and financial institutions". Yet, somehow I feel uncomfortable doing so, because banks themselves are financial institutions, too. Probably, the temptation to extract "banks" from "financial institutions" stems from the fact that banks constitute quite a big share of all financial institutions, including also brokerage firms, exchanges and more. So, from the perspective of marketing, I have a natural inclination to emphasize banks as a separate customer segment, but the linguistic consideration doesn't let me do it so easily.

Comment: If it bothers you, you could say "Banks and **other** financial institutions." The "other" would usually be assumed and understood, however, even if not stated explicitly.

Comment: Most people say [banks and other financial institutions](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=banks+and+financial+institutions%2Cbanks+and+other+financial+institutions&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbanks%20and%20financial%20institutions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbanks%20and%20other%20financial%20institutions%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: And, for completeness' sake, even many more people say simply [financial institutions](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=banks+and+financial+institutions%2Cbanks+and+other+financial+institutions%2Cfinancial+institutions&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbanks%20and%20financial%20institutions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbanks%20and%20other%20financial%20institutions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfinancial%20institutions%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: And, I suppose 'banks and [non-bank financial institutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-bank_financial_institution) (NBFIs)' just might be an option as well.

Comment: "Racial minorities and women have reason to fear the incoming administration."  The word "and" implies the "union" of the two terms being combined, so there is no need to explicitly (and clumsily) say, eg, "women who are not members of a racial minority".  But in the original example it is easy to insert "other", and it slightly clarifies the reference, so one might as well insert it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the term "banks and financial institutions" enjoys well-established precedent. Here are a few:

- The Law Library of Congress (America): [Archive for Topic: Banks and financial institutions (100 posts)](http://www.loc.gov/law/foreign-news/topic/banks-and-financial-institutions/);
- The Treasury (Australia): [Dealing with banks and financial institutions](http://www.treasury.gov.au/Policy-Topics/Business/Small-Business/Legal-Topics/Credit-and-Debt-Recovery/Provision-of-credit/Dealing);
- Swedbank (Norway and Baltic Region): [Banks and Financial Institutions](https://www.swedbank.com/corporate/banks-and-financialinstitutions/);
- Bank of England (UK): [In particular, domestic lending includes intragroup lending to other UK banks and financial institutions, whereas lending overseas excludes intragroup lending.](http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/publications/Documents/fsr/2011/fsr11jun2.ppt)
- [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=banks%20and%20financial%20institutions&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbanks%20and%20financial%20institutions%3B%2Cc0) (click on the date ranges below the chart).

Comment: You failed to Ngram the alternative term.

Comment: @HotLicks In this instance, I used Ngram for the references rather than for comparison, hence the comment in parentheses.

Answer (score -2):

Banks in America are either state (through the OCC) or federally chartered entities (through the FED), and they have are highly regulated from a host of federal and state agencies, like the FDIC and the CFPB.  Other financial institutions, such as brokerages or credit unions, may and will have other regulatory guidance and oversight.  The specific regulatory charters and guidance often shapes the form, the product mix and other primary characteristics of the organization.  So saying Bank to an industry insider will evoke a different organization in its entirety from a financial institution. It's completely commonplace to say banks and financial institutions therefore.

Answer (score -4):

banks are financial institutions .... so its not appropriate to use "banks and financial institutions"... it could be written as "financial institution like banks".